# Default timeout for Task.WaitAll()

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task, .net-4.5

What is the default timeout for `Task.WaitAll?` Is it infinite?
Is `Task.WaitAll(stuff.AsyncMethod());` equal to `Task.WaitAll(new Task[] { stuff.AsyncMethod() }, -1);` ?

I have tried Googling and chacked the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235688%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a method overload takes a `timespan timeout` as parameter while another doesn't, it implies the one that doesn't has no timeout (i.e. inifinite).

Here is the implementation:

```
public static void WaitAll(params Task[] tasks)
{
  Task.WaitAll(tasks, -1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's equivalent. Here's the method you're calling, which then calls the overload that accepts a timeout and passes `-1` by default:

```
public static void WaitAll(params Task[] tasks)
{
    Task.WaitAll(tasks, -1);
}
```

In the docs you linked, it says `-1` will "wait indefinitely".